# Windows 10 different login provider for different users possible?

Tags: windows-10

I am writing a new custom login provider for my own pc at home.

I just wanted to know if there is a way I can have my custom provider as default for all users but then have another account that uses the windows standard password provider? JUst in case MS decides to change the architecture and breaks my provider.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would advise to do your testing in a virtual machine, not in your own computer.
This is to avoid locking yourself out of your computer.

A default login provider is defined in the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc), at
*Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Logon*,
which is found in the entry of
"Assign a default credential provider" which is not configured by default.

If your default login provider works correctly, every user will have an option on the
login screen named "Sign-in options" that he can use for using other providers,
such as user-name plus password.

[image]

For more information see the article
[How to assign default Credential Provider in Windows 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/assign-default-credential-provider-windows-10).